# Challenging SQL to find previous record in a complex grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and hopefully help me find a solution.  I've been stuck for days now on this (but it seems like more).

I have an Oracle table that has 6 main columns:
1. grouping (Char)
2. Policy Number (Char(7) - but numeric with leading zeros)
3. Renewal number (Char(2) - but numeric with leading zeros)
4. Version number (Char(4) - but numeric with leading zeros)
5. Effective Date
6. Expiration Date

None of the columns are indexed but their is an index column.

What I need to do is:
1. find all records that are currently effective ([Expiration Date] >Sysdate)
2. find the previous policy number

Results I would like to get:

```
ID  Group  Policy    Renew      Ver    PrevID   PrevRenew   PrevVer
10    A      0001234    04     0003      3          04        0002
22    B      0001111    00     0001      12         00        0000
44    A      0003332    01     0000      31         00        0000
55    C      0003332    28     0010      4          28        0009
```

Rules are: 
  - that the policy and group always stay the same
  - unrelated policies can exist under diffrent groups
  - when a policy renews the version starts at "0000"
  - results may include a currently effective policy and another that will be effective in the future.  the previous policy of the later will of course be the current

the tricky part I am getting stuck on is if the Ver is '0000' and I decrease the value of Renew by one to get the PrevRenew, but then need to get the max of the Version for that to get the PrevVer.

My attempts at creating SQL have worked but they are terribly slow. Perhaps you know of a simple and faster way to accomplish the results I am attempting? I'd be more than happy to post what I have if it will be helpful.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you post your slow SQL attempts maybe someone can optimize it.

Comment: if you have a solution that is working (returning the expected results), please post it! It'll make the problem more easily understandable and straightforward and let us focus on the speeding it up part.

Comment: @Paul - What are the rules for determining the "previous policy number"?  Your results have an `ID` and `PrevID` column but `ID` is not one of the column that you listed in the "6 main columns" list.

Comment: And supplying the input data that yielded the example output data would help too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that by "previous policy number" you mean "return the `ID`, `Renew`, and `Ver` columns for the row that has the same `Group` and `Policy` and the immediately prior `Effective_Date`" you can use the analytic function `LAG`

```
SELECT id,
       group,
       policy,
       renew,
       ver,
       prevID,
       prevRenew,
       prevVer
  FROM (SELECT id,
               group,
               policy,
               renew,
               ver,
               expiration_date,
               lag(id) over (partition by group, policy 
                                 order by effective_date) prevID,
               lag(renew) over (partition by group, policy 
                                    order by effective_date) prevRenew,
               lag(ver) over (partition by group, policy 
                                  order by effective_date) prevVer
          FROM some_table)
 WHERE expiration_date > sysdate;
```

Comment: SWEET!  This works awesome!   You da Man! Thanks again Justin and all others who had willingness to help!